# Extracting data in java from a received java-script page

Tags: java, android, extract

I receive a java-script encoded page when I am doing the GET request for a search in Google api.
Now I need to extract the value of "unescapedUrl" and "titleNoFormatting" out of this. 
Normally in C++ I would use search by word and then use pointers to get the next coming characters, but I have no idea what to do in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I receive a java-script encoded page when i am doing the GET request for a search in Google api.

This appears to be mostly JSON.

> normally in c++ i would use search by word and then use pointers to get the next coming characters

If so, and if this is JSON output, then a C++ developer should use a JSON parsing library.

> but i have no idea what to do in java.

Similarly, a Java developer should use a JSON parsing library. Android has the org.json parsing classes built in, and there is a separate `JSONReader` (based on GSON) in Android 3.x.